# MySQL LEFT JOIN using MAX & GROUP BY on joined table and Get other columns that correspond with MAX value of one column?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`ClientName`, b.id as ActivityId, max(b.DueDate) 
FROM `clients` as `a`
LEFT JOIN activities b on b.ClientId = a.id 
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
```

How do you get the rows that correspond with MAX value ?
Here I am getting the correct Max DueDate but ActivityId doesn't correspond with MAX  DueDate row

link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbe1a/1)

in this demo exmaple link: here max DueDate is 2017-07-10 its correct. ActivityId in incorrect. its showing as 1 but it should show 2. Please check the screenshot

Comment: Can you post some sample data in both tables and expected results?

Comment: You'll want this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: It doesn't make sense to not grouping the ClientName and ActivityId.  If there are multiple ActivityId, you don't know which ones will get picked up if it's not in the grouping.  In fact, it's not allowed in other dbms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume this is your `clients` table:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientName varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO clients
VALUES
    (1, 'Client 1'),
    (2, 'Client 2') ;
```

And this are your `activities`

```
CREATE TABLE activities
(
   id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   ClientId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES client(id),
   DueDate DATE NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO activities
VALUES
   (1, 1, '2017-01-01'),
   (2, 1, '2017-12-31'),
   (3, 1, '2017-05-05'),
   (4, 2, '2017-01-03'),
   (5, 2, '2017-03-04'),
   (6, 2, '2017-06-07') ;
```

(If using MySQL/MariaDB: we make sure we `GROUP BY` using the SQL standard, to avoid mistakes. If using PostgreSQL, omit it; PostgreSQL `GROUP BY` already follow the SQL standard with regard to this)

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' ;
```

We first make one *simple* `GROUP BY` to get the `MAX(DueDate)` for every single `ClientId`:

```
SELECT
   ClientId, max(DueDate) AS MaxDate
FROM 
   activities 
GROUP BY 
   ClientId ;
```

We get:

```
ClientId | MaxDate   
-------: | :---------
       1 | 2017-12-31
       2 | 2017-06-07
```

Having this result, we wrap it as a subquery (`q0`), and `JOIN` it with the `activites` table, to retrieve the corresponding activty.
We also `JOIN` it with `clients` to retrieve the client data:

```
SELECT
    c.ClientName, q0.ClientId, a.id AS ActivityId, a.DueDate
FROM
    (SELECT
       ClientId, max(DueDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM 
       activities 
    GROUP BY 
       ClientId 
    ) AS q0 
    JOIN activities a ON a.ClientId = q0.ClientId AND a.DueDate = q0.MaxDate 
    RIGHT JOIN clients c ON c.id = q0.ClientId 
ORDER BY
    c.ClientName ;
```

And we get:

```
ClientName | ClientId | ActivityId | DueDate   
:--------- | -------: | ---------: | :---------
Client 1   |        1 |          2 | 2017-12-31
Client 2   |        2 |          6 | 2017-06-07
```

You can check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0a4a6cdcda56347ee75b512cfaff4624)*

NOTE: as per your comments, `RIGHT JOIN` if you need all *clients*, even if they don't have activities. `JOIN` would give only the ones *with* activities.

---

**Note**: This is SQL standard, not only MySQL or PostgreSQL.

**Caveat**: if *two or more* activities happen to coincide with the `Max(DueDate)` you will get them all.

If that can happen and you want just *one*, you can work your way out without a JOIN, but with a *subquery* with a certain `ORDER BY` (to prioritize which one you actually want if there are more than one) and a `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Here i am trying to left join. so if i have (3, 'Client 3')  , ActivityId and duedate shoule be null

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If so, mark the answer as *accepted* so that people can concentrate on the *unanswered* questions.

Comment: Here i am trying to left join. so if i have insert  (3, 'Client 3') in clients , ActivityId and duedate shoule be nul

Comment: Here there is a small edit to your query just added 'right'..            
 SELECT c.ClientName,
       q0.ClientId,
       a.id AS ActivityId,
       a.DueDate
FROM
  (SELECT ClientId,
          max(DueDate) AS MaxDate
   FROM activities
   GROUP BY ClientId) AS q0
JOIN activities a ON a.ClientId = q0.ClientId
AND a.DueDate = q0.MaxDate
RIGHT JOIN clients c ON c.id = q0.ClientId
ORDER BY c.ClientName. Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

For grouping , you need to group all the columns that are in your select statement as :

```
SELECT
  `a`.`id`,
  `a`.`ClientName`,
   b.id as ActivityId,
   b.DueDate
FROM `clients` as `a`
  LEFT JOIN activities b on b.ClientId = a.id
Where b.DueDate in (select max(DueDate) from activities)
GROUP BY `a`.`id`;
```

Comment: no Sorry. this is giving me multiple id. i need only group by id

Comment: any sample data and expected output ?

Comment: yeah ! now please tell what result you want ?

Comment: here max DueDate is 2017-07-10 its correct. ActivityId in incorrect. its showing as 1 but it should show 2